# How to change data format in write function in Python?

Tags: python

How to change the data format in f.write function?

loaded_data = 349.00  or 3.00

I want to change data format in write function like %6f in print function.

ex)  349.00 -> 349.000000 ,   3.00 -> 3.000000

```
f = open("test.txt", 'w')
f.write( str.(loaded_data).zfill(?) )
```

What is the code that performs above function?

Answer (score 2):

you can use:

```
>>> loaded_data = 349.00
>>> str.format('{0:.6f}', loaded_data)
'349.000000'
```

or

```
>>> loaded_data = 349.00
>>> "%.6f" % loaded_data
'349.000000'
```